# Maxima CAS; how to use simp flag locally in block

Tags: maxima

Question is: how to make simp-flag:false inside block, or if stattment and leaving it return simp-flag:true?

Multiplying numerator and nominator, I want to exclude simplification, **localy**, to get output equation in desired form:

from this:

```
(%i1)   ec:-((E1*Z2)/(ZC^2-Z1*Z2));
(%o1)   -(E1*Z2)/(ZC^2-Z1*Z2)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4t8J.png)
I want this:

```
(%i2)   -((E1*Z2)/Z1)/(ZC^2/Z1-Z2);
(%o2)   -((E1*Z2)/Z1)/(ZC^2/Z1-Z2)
```

using something like:

```
(%i3)   numdenmul(expr, mul) :=
       if op(expr) = "-" then - numdenmul(- expr, mul)
       elseif op(expr) = "/" then apply("/", expand(mul *
    args(expr)))
       else expr   $
(%i5)   simp;
(%o5)   true
(%i6)   numdenmul(ec,1/Z1);
(%o6)   -(E1*Z2)/(Z1*(ZC^2/Z1-Z2))
```

not desired result, so i try to exclude simplification:

```
(%i10)  numdenmul1(expr, mul) :=
        block ( [m,m1], 
        if op(expr) = "-" then - numdenmul1(- expr, mul)
       elseif op(expr) = "/" then 
        (
        m:expand (args(expr)* mul),
        simp:false,
        m1:apply("/",m) 
        )
       else expr   )$
(%i9)   numdenmul1(ec,1/Z1);
(%o9)   -((E1*Z2)/Z1)/(ZC^2/Z1-Z2)
```

Result is satisfaying, but **flag simp is not block - local**, it remained false after applying function numdenmul1:

( Optimal result would be without minus sign in front of fraction, swapping position of numerator arguments.)

```
(%i11)  simp;
(%o11)  false
```

i tried:

```
    block var declare block ( [m,m1,simp] ... no efect

    ev(m1:apply("/",m), simp:false)       ... no efect

    return (m1), simp:true                ... no efect
```

from manual ?ev :

The simp, numer, and float switches may also be set locally in a block,
or
globally in Maxima so that they will remain in effect until being reset.

According upper statement, flag should be local inside block by default ?

Comment: Disabling simp in second case i get desired output...
Desired flow is: 
Set global variable, apply some changes on data, make output, reset global variable.
Do it in a single cell.
Trouble making fact is that block, if, lambda, (expr, ..., expr), return ...
They all have last command output, whitch is reset global variable, not data output.
Solved making batch file...

Answer (score 0):

There may be a way to do it that I'm not seeing, but I'm pretty sure it's not possible to get the result you want without disabling simplification entirely. The reason `block([simp: false], ...)` doesn't have the result you want is that Maxima applies simplification to function return values, so even if the function produces an unsimplified expression, it gets simplified by the time you see it.

You can get the result by disabling simplification, or by protecting the expression from simplification, but either way that is kind of heavy-handed; it prevents the expression from being used in any ordinary way, since many basic operations are implemented as simplifications, and Maxima functions generally expect expressions to have a standard form which is produced by simplification.

Comment: Solved making batch file...

(smp:simp,
block ([m,m1,a],
    simp:true, a:"+",  
    loop,
    if op(expr) = "-" then (a:"-",expr:-expr, go(loop))
   elseif op(expr) = "/" then 
    (
    m:(expand (args(expr)* mul)),display(m,a),
    simp:false,
    m1:a(apply("/",m))                    
    )
   else expr   )),
simp:smp;